# JSONObject automatically add \ to values [Razorpay Order_id doesn't work for that reason]

Tags: java, android, json, razorpay

I am using **razorpay** payment gateway in my android application. I fetch my *orderid* from the server and store it in a JSON object. After putting values to JSON object I call the payment gateway function.
The problem is that the gateway returns an error because the *orderid* is invalid.
Suppose my *orderid* is as follows:`order_ABC8324kbsjdf`.When I logged the *orderid* before adding it to the JSON object was in the correct format, but when I logged the response I found that a `\` is attached to the *orderid* and the `order` part removed. Is there any way to fix it?

```
final Checkout co = new Checkout();
    try {
        JSONObject options = new JSONObject();
        options.put("key","rzp_test_HxDYx5i6JW1Ujd");
        options.put("name", "Commission Calculator");
        options.put("description", "Buy serial key");
        //You can omit the image option to fetch the image from dashboard
        options.put("image", "https://rzp-mobile.s3.amazonaws.com/images/rzp.png");
        //order_id=order_id.replace("\\\\","");
        Log.d("ORDER",order_id);

        options.put("order_id",order_id);
        options.put("currency", "INR");

        String payment = editTextPayment.getText().toString();

        double total = Double.parseDouble(payment);
        total = total * 100;
        options.put("amount", total);

        JSONObject preFill = new JSONObject();
        preFill.put("email", "sikander@gkmit.co");
        preFill.put("contact", "9680224241");

        options.put("prefill", preFill);

        co.open(activity, options);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(activity, "Error in payment: " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

[image: Order ID log]

[image: response log]

Comment: try using gson and see
https://github.com/google/gson

Comment: I will try it.Thank you

Comment: You can use this for getting the model classes for faster delevopment
http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/ sorry for the delay